# How to set netty 4 thread name?

Tags: netty, threadpool

The default thread name is nioEventLoopGroup-x-x, how can I customize it? It seems be available in netty 3 with ThreadRenamingRunnable. But it's removed in netty4.

Comment: You need to provide custom `java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory` to constructor of your `EventLoopGroup`

Answer (score 1):

Just inject your own `ThreadFactory` in the `NioEventLoopGroup` or use the `DefaultThreadFactory` of netty and configure it accordantly before injecting it.